# DLL load error with Gdal polygonize in QGIS 1.8 (windows 7)

Tags: qgis, gdal, polygonize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Qgis polygonize problem - DLL load fail](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28667/qgis-polygonize-problem-dll-load-fail)

[I had already posted this question, but was closed and redirected to a supposedly duplicate question. I'm re-posting since I believe this is note exactly the same case.]

I'm getting the following error message when I try to use the polygonize tool in QGIS 1.8 (windows 7):

Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\bin\gdal_polygonize.py", line 34, in 
import gdal, ogr, osr 
File "C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\gdal.py", line 2, in 
from osgeo.gdal import deprecation_warn 
File "C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo__init__.py", line 21, in 
_gdal = swig_import_helper() 
File "C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper 
_mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description) 
ImportError: DLL load failed: No se encontró el proceso especificado.

I have already tried or checked the following with no success:

- Making sure there is no PYTHONPATH variable
- adding "C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\bin\", "C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\bin" and "C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\" to the beginning of PATH variable
- Checking that GDAL was not installed separately
- Installed Visual Basic 2010 Express (couldn't find Visual Studio 2010 as suggested in the other post)
- "Path to the GDAL executables" and "Path to the GDAL Python modules" are blank in he GDAL setting menu within QGIS.

Any ideas what this could be? 
I wonder why would it be the path variable if all other Gdal are working fine. Wouldn't it have a DLL load error for all or other Gdal modules?

Answer (score 1):

Installing Qgis in a folder without blanks will solve a lot of problems related to that.
The osgeo4w-setup is one option for it.

Comment: I just tried installing QGIS in a folder without blanks --didn't work, I still have the same problem

Comment: OK next possibilities: Has your Windows user name non-ASCII characters? Is there another installation of python or gdal on your computer which might interfere?

Comment: Thank you for keeping up with the help, @Andre, I just checked your suggestions. My Windows user name is plainly "andres", so that cannot be the problem. I only have one version of Python installed (2.7). I do not know how to check the gdal installation (I didn't install it myself; it got installed when I installed the QGIS standalone installer). No other QGIS version is installed either.

Comment: With the installation, you got a OSGEoW icon. If you start that, you should get a list of available Gdal tools, and the version  info. That should be 1.9.1. Alternatively, you can try the OSgeo4w setup of Qgis, which will install to C:\Osgeo4W, and has its own gdal with it. Maybe that solves your problem. And/or you can install qgis-dev from Osgeo4W setup with gdal 1.9.2.

Comment: problem solved! Thank you so much. Just one question: On the  OSgeo4w icon it says the gdal version is 1.7.3. How can I upgrade it to 1.9.2?

Comment: That's rather strange, because the standalone installer Lisboa comes with 1.9.1. I wonder where you got 1.7.3 from. You can check it also with Help->About inside Qgis Menu bar. The osgeo4w-Setup, which installs to C:\Osgeo4w, allows you to update every package with advanced install-> View complete. But this does not change the gdal version of standalone installation.